# Advancing the auto-generated Id of the SharePoint lists

Tags: sharepoint-online, id, auto-increment

While moving data from old lists to new ones (some migration scenarios), we frequently have a requirement to advance the auto-generated Id of the list items in the target list. By default, Id starts with 1 and is incremented by 1 for every item created in the list. Currently we create and delete dummy items to advance the Id. Is there a better way to do it? I need it mainly in SharePoint online. But having a solution just for on-premises will also be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As a dumb solution, you can use a separate column, which will be updated by workflow on item creation event. And stop using Id column completely.
i.e. in workflow the only action is set *YourIdColumn = ItemId + some constant increment number*.

Comment: With Id column value, we can directly do GetItemById. There is no fixed increment as advancing may be done more than once, so we cannot get Id back from any custom column.